# Not able to get child property in parent.jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have `parent.jsp` and i am including `child.html` page as `Jsp:include` in parent.jsp.

I have one img tag inside child.html that i want to access in my parent.jsp

I put below code in document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            var imgSrc = $("img").attr("src");
            alert(imgSrc);
});
```

It alerts **undefined** to me. Does anyone has idea ?

Comment: please add parent.jsp and child.jsp page .

Answer (score 0):

`$("img")` returns a collection of all images on the page , use an index with it.

like :

```
var imgSrc = $("img")[0].attr("src");
             alert(imgSrc);
```

Answer (score 0):

To alert all image src's you need to do something this

```
$("img").each(function() {  
   imgsrc = this.src;
    alert(imgsrc);
  });
```

Comment: You are right, but my parent jsp can not recognize my included html file's image tag